# size_t format warning with gcc std=gnu90

Tags: c, string-formatting, gcc-warning, size-t

I am currently working on a software project in C which has to run on a variety of platforms. I try to remain as close to the C90 standard as possible, but need some commonly supported extensions like stdint.h and an unsigned long long type. I deliberately do not want to "fall back" to the C99 standard since some of the compilers that I use do not support all C99 features like mixed declarations and code etc.

Thus, I currently compile all my code with gcc on my (64-bit Ubuntu) development machine with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu90` (not C90 due to my use of unsigned long long etc. as described above) to address all non-format-compliant code parts. So far, I could adapt my code to get rid of all warnings but one: I cannot find a proper (printf) format for size_t that does not yield a warning from gcc. Consider the following example code which illustrates most of the things that I tried:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("%zu", sizeof(int)); /* C99 format specifier for size_t */
  printf("%u", sizeof(int)); /* Treat size_t as unsigned int */
  printf("%lu", sizeof(int)); /* Treat size_t as unsigned long int (only works when size_t is "typedef"ed to unsigned long int) */
  return 0;
}
```

When compiled with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu90`, I get warnings for the first two lines:

> test.c:6:3: warning: ISO C90 does not support the ‘z’ gnu_printf length modifier [-Wformat=]
>   test.c:7:3: warning: format ‘%u’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]

Although I do not get a warning for the third line, this is only the case on my development system. On other systems, specifically on those where size_t is some "custom" type or not "typedef"ed as unsigned long long, there will still be a warning.

I am well aware that there is no format specifier for size_t in C90, but that there is one in C99. However, I thought that setting `-std=gnu90` would give me the 'z' format specifier, but that assumption turned out to be incorrect.

Since I could not get rid of the warning(s), I tried to define a format specifier with some preprocessor definitions like this:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef __GNUC__
  #define GLUE(x, y, z) x##y##z
  #define GLUE_FORMAT(prefix, size) GLUE(PRI, prefix, size)
  #define UINT_FORMAT(size) GLUE_FORMAT(u, size)
  #define SIZE_T_FORMAT UINT_FORMAT(__SIZEOF_SIZE_T__)
#else /* C99 fall-back */
  #define SIZE_T_FORMAT "zu"
#endif

int main()
{
  printf("%" SIZE_T_FORMAT, sizeof(int));
  return 0;
}
```

I thought that this should give me the proper format specifier, the only constraint being that size_t is unsigned (which it is on all my target platforms so far). However, that does not work either:

> test.c:15:3: warning: format ‘%u’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]

Is there any way, given the constraints, to overcome this warning (or to find a more elegant solution without resorting to `-std=c99`)?

Comment: @Coconop: %lu would work on my development platform, but not on some others

Comment: @Coconop: I added a short explanation to my original post and updated the code.

Comment: Where does `__SIZEOF_SIZE_T__` come from? `grep __SIZEOF_SIZE_T__ /usr/include/ -rw` on my recent Debian gives me nothing ... :-S

Comment: @alk: That's defined in one of the headers from the GNU extensions

Comment: Normally under C89/C90, you'd use `%lu` and cast the result of the sizeof expression to `unsigned long`.

Comment: @alk: My mistake, it seems to be defined by gcc (built-in macro)

Comment: So what is `__SIZEOF_SIZE_T__` though? Probably `8`, whereas the `PRI*` defines use the size in **bits**, so 64 would be correct here.

Comment: @JohnBode: That's only fine until I'm on a platform where size_t is unsigned long long

Comment: @alk: You are right. I totally missed that. Unfortunately, defining something like `#define SIZE_T_SIZE (8 * __SIZEOF_SIZE_T__) and using that as an argument to the UINT_FORMAT macro yields a syntax error

Comment: in general, the format specifier should match the data being displayed.  One of the warnings clearly states that size_t is unsigned long.  So I would do two things.  1) cast the parameter using (unsigned long)  2) use the %lu format specifier.  The 'z'  is (usually) not available, so, for portability, do not use it,.

Answer (score 1):

Would you consider a cast? Casting is normally a sign of problems, but at some point it might be simplest to just write

```
printf("%u", (unsigned) sizeof(int));
```

You could even combine the cast into a macro

```
#define usizeof(a) ((unsigned)sizeof(a))
printf("%u", usizeof(int));
```

which would make it easy enough to use.

Comment: To elaborate on my comment from above regarding this suggestion: This is fine on some systems, but if size_t is "typedef"ed as unsigned long long, it might cause problems due to the downcast.

Comment: @AndreasUnterweger cast up to the maximum then  (set your headers up so the maximum int type and its printf format is available)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Works like charm. Thank you. It should be noted, however, that `-Wno-long-long` is required on some platforms so that the warnings are not replaced by new ones which complain about the "ll" format specifier. Would you care to expand your comment into an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: given the 'sizeof' is a magnitude only operator, (and really should not be typedef'd to any specific number of bits.  it should always be cast when printing

Comment: @user3629249: Well, most implementations just typedef size_t to one of the pre-defined int types. In addition, sometimes one needs to print an argument of size_t, e.g., when an allocation fails and malloc's argument is included in the error message, like "Unable to allocate %zu bytes"